# Calculate and Display Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have scores being submitted by three users and would like to display the average score to the nearest tenth's place.  Currently, I am using the query:

```
SELECT AVG(score) as AverageScore
FROM PoemScores
WHERE poemID = #qGetPoems.poemid#
```

I am able to output AverageScore, but only as a whole number using `#getScore.AverageScore#`.  How can I output the average score in the format n.n? The database is MSSQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your database engine, you probably just need to cast the score as a decimal or a float before averaging it.

possible mysql approach:

```
select CAST(
            AVG(
                CAST(score as decimal(8,1))
            )
           as decimal(8,1)
           ) as AverageScore
```

possible mssql approach:

```
 select convert(float(8,1), AVG( convert(float(8,1), score) ) ) as AverageScore
```